# error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Python

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm using flask to run a simple web server to display my video output from the webcam as an mjpeg, i need to use the link to stream it on Mission planner, my code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/video_feed')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
        #time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/vid.jpg')
def video_feed():
    time.sleep(1)
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
#multipart/x-mixed-replace

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=54223)
```

when i access the link via chrome it works fine but when i use the same link on mission planners as a mjpeg source, i get this response from the shell:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54225)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Am i doing anything wrong? I am using windows 10.